# In aws-Route53 showing no targets available for linking domain with my ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image: my regions for Route53]

[image: my regions of ec2 instance]

[image: targets]

First image is my regions of Routes3
second image id my region of Ec2 instance where django hosted

third image is targets to choose my domain.

It is showing no targets available in the third image.

is there any issue with regions?

are the regions must same?

please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have a Route 53 record pointing to an EC2 instance then you should do a simple A record (not an Alias one) which value is the public IP of the EC2 instance.

You cannot have an EC2 instance as an [Alias Target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html)